# Telerik MVC DatePicker set to null or empty ASP C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, datepicker

I have a telerik datepicker, and I'm trying to get it to allow me to set its value to null or empty.  It seems this should be supported, but it doesn't work with:

- BeginDate (Nullable DateTime)
- BeginDate != null ? BeginDate.ToShortDateString() : "" (Empty String when null)
- BeginDate ?? DateTime.MinValue (DateTime)

  @Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("BeginDate").Value(item.BeginDate)

Is this doable?  Seems like it should be.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of issues (error messages, behavioral quirks etc.) are you running into?

Using the following class (just as an example):

```
public class BindingClass
{
    public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then this Razor markup:

```
@model BindingClass

    @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
            .Name("Test")
            .Value(Model.BeginDate)
    )
```

My DatePicker works fine. The initial value is null (the DatePicker is empty) and I can select a date from the DatePicker calendar.

Have you tried using this with the latest version (2011.3.1115.340)? Perhaps there is an issue with an older version that you are using.